# How to run java script code without writing this "const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({sigint: true});"in the beginning of the code?

Tags: javascript

I recently Insall the node.js and visual code studio to run java script in computer.
And I got the error a while running "prompt not defined.".

I research in internet and got that we need to add :
1.npm install prompt-sync
2.const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({sigint: true});(in beginning of every program).

I need the solution that solve not to write (const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({sigint: true}); ) in every program beginning.

Comment: Well don't use `prompt` in every program?!

Comment: I am just beginning the java script, then what can I thought for it then??

Comment: What programming are you doing that requires prompting?

Comment: simple to ask name and print i.e. I think a basic program to the start java script.  var var fname=prompt("enter the first namre");
var lname=prompt("enter the last namre");
console.log("Your name is :",fname,lname);

Comment: @SudipSharma — It's starting to sound like you need to **not** try to combine Node.js with an introductory JavaScript tutorial that assumes you are running your code in a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js has no built-in method for prompting the user for input. (Browsers have a built-in [`prompt` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), but Node.js isn't a browser.)

If you want to read user input using something that works like prompt then you need to either use a third-party module (like `prompt-sync`, which you've rejected) or to recreate the functionality you need from scratch (which, [judging from the source code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync?activeTab=code) will be a **lot** more work each program).

Comment: One could argue that nodejs' builtin prompting functionality is the asynchronous `readline`

Comment: I am not arguing about the node.js tool but what is the solution I am just asking that.

Comment: @SudipSharma — The solution is to suck it up and install and `require` `prompt-sync` if you want the functionality of `prompt-sync`.

Comment: I type require prompt sync in terminal in vs code, but it did not work.